# chrome site info not readable nor clickable

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

I've run into a problem with google chrome after reinstalling a pc of mine.
Whenever I try to click on the connection info....an almost blank box appears instead of the normal screen. The same is also true when a download starts via google chrome. The block or do window has the same problem and is unclickable.

[image]

Now my question is: What can I do to avoid this problem? (thus getting rid of the display error and being ablet o click into the "popup" again).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After noticing that it doesnt only happen for the site info, but also for every popup that chrome has I found out that the main reason was a font problem.

Seemingly it was caused by the advanced settings option "Hardware acceleration". Disabling this setting made it all visible again.